# Calling Async and Sync Method on EJB Singleton

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, singleton, ejb-3.1

I am trying to achieve the following :

**EJB3 Singleton**

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class SomeSingleton implements SomeSingletonRemote  {

    @override
    @Asynchronous
    public void someLongStuff(){
        method1();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        method2();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        // ...
    }

    public void method1(){
        // Insert an Event in a Database.
    }

    public void method2(){
        // Insert an Event in a Database.
    }

    public void someShortStuff(){
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Managed Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SomeManagedBean{

    @EJB
    private SomeSingletonRemote _singleton;

    public void someLongStuff(){
        _singleton.someLongStuff();
    }

    public void someShortStuff(){
        _singleton.someShortStuff();
    } 
}
```

**JSF using PrimeFace**

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Start Long Stuff" 
        actionListener="#{SomeManagedBean.someLongStuff}" />
    <p:commandButton value="Start Short Stuff"
        actionListener="#{SomeManagedBean.someShortStuff}" />
</h:form>
```

The above code doesn't work asynchronously. When the *"Start Long Stuff"* button is pressed, we have to wait until the method is finished to be able to press the other button.
Can you tell me were I am wrong ?

Comment: There are cases wherein it may fail (e.g. async method actually not called by client, but only internally by service), but yours looks fine (yes, that annotation on managed bean method is totally useless). So, the cause of your problem is not visible in the information provided so far, unless you actually didn't post a true MCVE at all.

Comment: I tried to add more details in the code but i dont think it helps. By the way, thanks for your time.

Comment: So it's a remote EJB?

Comment: Yes, It's a Remote EJB. The @Asynchronous annotation doesn't work in that case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singleton session beans by default use container-managed concurrency with write locks, which means all methods are exclusive.  If you want to allow multiple methods to be called on the EJB simultaneously, you either need to use bean managed concurrency:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@ConcurrencyManagement(BEAN)
public class SomeSingleton implements SomeSingletonRemote  {
```

...or you need to specify read locks:

```
@override
@Asynchronous
@Lock(READ)
public void someLongStuff(){ ... }
...

@Lock(READ)
public void someShortStuff(){
    // ...
}
```

If your bean methods are doing write operations, it probably makes more sense conceptually to use bean-managed concurrency rather than `@Lock(READ)`.

Comment: So it will not work with just the @Asynchronous with **locals** interfaces ?

Comment: @CharlesFollet Singleton locking behavior is orthogonal to local/remote, so the effect I describe will happen regardless.  Perhaps I've misunderstood your question, but what led you to believe the locking behavior might only apply to remote?

Comment: Maybe because BalusC asked for. I don't know. Thank you anyway for your very clear answer

Comment: @CharlesFollet Ah, I didn't see that.  He is a known JSF expert, but I'm not sure what he had in mind with his line of thinking.